# JS. I want to store function to object and then use it as anonymus

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have an object like this:

```
window.socketFunctions = {
    waybillDocCreated: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

than i want to use it in socket:

```
if (window.socketFunctions){
    for (var name in window.socketFunctions){
         socket.on(name, window.socketFunctions[name]);
    }
}
```

like this:

```
socket.on('suitable', function(data){
      var badge = $('#suitableBadge');
      if(badge.length){
           badge.addClass('label-danger');
           badge.addClass('label');
           var count = parseInt(badge.html() || 0);
           badge.html(++count);
      }
});
```

After this code it saves my function as waybillDocCreated(), but .on('suitable') saves it like anonymous

Comment: Yes, you didn't put the `suitable` callback in the `socketFunctions`. Now [how is that a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: Why would you want to attach the functions to window? Have you tried: `window.socketFunctions = {suitable: function waybillDocCreated(data){console.log(data);}}` ?

Comment: I don't understand the question :S